# Why won't my image update in an iOS control?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a bundle with images in it for buttons. I changed a number of these files, but all are still showing as the old image when I build and deploy to device or simulator. Is there something I can do to get the build or device to realize that these images have changed? When I view the image in Xcode, it shows the new image (same file name, but updated image). When I deploy it, it shows the old image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes Xcode has caching issues with build artifacts. Try doing a clean first, then build.

Comment: Definitely try doing a clean, if you swap files out from underneath Xcode it doesn't know to update those files in the build directory so it will re-use what it already had in order to reduce compile time.

Comment: Ahh! I should have known, after having to clean every 15 minutes in Eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove derived data which is located here: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<YourAppName>-<some_hash>`

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Xcode project settings 'Build Phases' / 'Copy Bundle Resources' to make sure the images 'you think' (the updated ones), are included in the bundle and not an old reference.

Failing that have you tried a 'Clean & Build', or delete the App from the device / simulator and re-build it.

Answer (score 0):

2 things that typically solve the problem:

1. Do a "Clean"
2. Delete the app from the device/simulator

Comment: I tried number 2 before posting without luck. It was the clean that did it.

Answer (score 0):

Clean is Shift+Command+K or -->product --> clean 
for newbs like me who didn't know what clean was.